# Can I input Product detail in Second line in Shopping Cart on Product name

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, product, cart

Can I insert Product detail (Promotion or Free goods) if product have in Second line in Shopping Cart on Product name?

**P.S.** 
This page not render table of product list  in cart.phtml or cart.php and i can't insert data in

```
<.th> name <./th>
```

Like other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the cart page than have a look on

> template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml

May be you can modify in this file to fulfill your requirement.

Hope this will help.